# Best iOS Backend for Simple Push and Get

Tags: iphone, ios, cloud, backend, parse-platform

Which backend should I use in my app? Basically I want a user to be able to submit a number to the cloud, and have another user be able to receive it.

Is Parse.com the best solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more) might help you make a choice. 
I have seen a couple of projects that initially used parse, but later on switched to [helios](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/2/helios)
. Main reasons being transparency of costs and flexibility.